Preimage of a linear map
Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a linear map between vector spaces $X,Y$ and $Z$ a subset of $Y$ such that the preimage $f^{-1}(Z)$ is a subspace of $X$.
Is it then true that $Z$ must be a subspace of $Y$ as well?
My feeling says yes, but I cant think of a proof attempt.
edit: I indeed forgot to say that f is an epimorphism. But the answer even answered both questions!

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

This is only true if $f$ is a surjection.
Consider, for instance, $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ with $f(x) = (x,x)$. Then the set $Z = \{(0,0),(1,-1)\}$ is certainly not a subspace, but $f^{-1}[Z] = \{0\}$ is the zero subspace.
However, if $f$ is surjective then you can use the definition of subspace and preimage. The key point is that

 Now every point in $Z$ is the image of some point in $f^{-1}[Z]$, which we know is a subspace.

